# basic php form doesnt work

Tags: php, forms, post

I am new in PHP and trying to save input to a text file, but POST action does nothing:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="usersname"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Write" name="submitwrite"/>
</form>
```

and in the same file on the top:

```
<?php
    // Check if the user submitted this form
if (isset($_POST["submitwrite"])) {
    // Open the file in write mode
    $handle = fopen("writetest.txt","a+"); 

    // If successful
    if ($handle) {
        // Write to that handle the username submitted in the form and the date
        fwrite($handle,$_POST["usersname"] . " - " . date("Y-m-d"));

        // Close the file
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
?>
```

I click button and it doesnt POST to itself.... how to fix it??

UPDATE:  Thank you for your answers.. A problem was with file permissions... server does not allow me to set 777, only 755. There was nothing wrong with this code. I am glad you helped me to spot this !!

Comment: If you want it to POST to itself, just omit the action attribute: `<form method="POST">`

Comment: the <?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?> expected echo before var. But if the form page and form processing is the same page you don't need print anything in action attribute

Comment: I think the form will actually post ok... Are you sure its not posting? On such a small script locally it would be very quick, and the page won't change... Add some debugging code, var_dump($_POST) in the if statement and see if it's executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your permissions to read/write for both User and IUSR on "writetest.txt" if you're testing locally.

**Steps to Fix it:**

- Right click the file "writetest.txt"
- Go to Properties.
- Click Security.
- Click Edit. Select IUSR and USER
- Check the "Write" box on both users.
- Save the settings.

Comment: It's strictly permissions. His code is running but because it doesn't have permission to write to the file - it doesn't. You need to grant it permission - not change the code.

Answer (score 3):

What does `<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>` do? It doesn't print anything, so your form doesn't have a place to submit to.

Try using `<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>` or `<?php print($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>` instead.

---

Also, if that won't help, maybe changing `fopen("writetest.txt","a+");` to `fopen("writetest.txt","w");` might help?

Comment: And empty action would actually end up posting to itself anyway... even though they would have been trying to do an echo.

Comment: Would an empty `action=` do the same thing as an omitted `action=`?

Comment: Just tested in Chrome and IE 9... And both did the same, posted to itself.

Comment: Huh, then maybe that's not the problem at all. But wouldn't that statement cause a PHP error message? Maybe that's what is not allowing the form to submit...

Comment: I commented my assumption on the answer, I believe the form may actually be posting, but there is no change to the page caused by the php.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity (man, I just can't type today). I was meaning that if the statement `<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>` were to be run, then PHP would fuss and stop execution by throwing an error, which would prevent the script from continuing any further.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that statement tho... It just doesn't do anything. e.g. `1;` is a valid statement.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to echo the action. But it doesn't matter, since you should omit the attribute completely if you want to POST to the same URL.

Comment: +1. I didn't know you didn't have to supply a `action=` if you're submitting to the same page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me your code works fine, but, I think that you doesn't work because the directory haven't permission for write.

run `chmod 0777 diretory_name`

Comment: permisions are 755 and server doesn't allow me to bump up to 777 for write access on the folder :(  what are the options..?

Comment: the server allow you to set show errors? ini_set('display_errors', 1) ? For you see the real error

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>` isn't doing what you expect it to.

If I recall correctly if you can avoid the problem by removing the `action` attribute, then the form will default to posting to "itself" (the same URL).

Comment: A cunning way to test to see if the form is being submitted is to try refreshing the page after clicking the button. If the browser asks if you want to resend your POST request, then the button worked; otherwise, it didn't. Or you could just write to the HTML whether it is a GET or POST request, that would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an echo in the action php statement. However the form should still post to itself.

Try:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Comment: get this at the page: array
  empty

Comment: Only after you click the button? That's unusual. That means the page is being posted to, but no data is being passed through.